# How to Restore Same Site Backup in Same Content DB to create another site collection in the same web application?

Tags: site-collection, web-application, content-database

I have a site backup and i want to create two site collection from that backup in one web application.when i try to restore second site collection on same web application it restrict me to do so.As site backup is of size 2 gb hence i even can not save it as template.this is a publishing site.

When i Tried to Restore-SPSite i get the error. "The operation that you are attempting to perform cannot be completed successfully.No Content database in the web application were available to store your sitecollection" The existing content database may have reached maximum no of sitecollection or be set to read only or be offline or may contain a copy of sitecollection."

***In My case Content DB allready containing  a copy of site collection***

Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i already have tried Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite and export/import, But this does not full fill my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for restore failure**: 
You need to understand the fact that whenever you try to restore a site collection backup to the same content database from which the site backup was taken , there will be a GUID conflict. GUID for a site collection is unique and it gets stored along with the site collection backup.

Your content database has a table called **dbo.sites** with a column named **"id"** Refer to the screenshot below

[image]

This id should always remain unique for site collections inside a single content database.Your restore will fail as long as this guid is not changed.

**Suggested Workaround** 
Save the site as a template through command line or powershell. Go to Central Admin and create a new site collection without selecting any template (select choose a template later option) during creation.  Restore the site template with overwriting this new site collection.

Refer to this link below :- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcollaboration/thread/b14e572a-ea17-47b4-93fe-4694451efe35

This workaround assumes that your site collection size isnt really that big and the custom solutions (wsps) are in a deployed/activated state at the web application level.

Answer (score -2):

You can use PowerShell to achieve this with these commands: Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite.
Here's a useful link with instructions on how to do this: http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com.ar/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-backuprestore-with.html

Comment: I think it will be an export/import, not a backup/restore that is required http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx since restoring from a backup will prevent it from being restored since it will refrence the same GUIDs for the site

Comment: export/import is also taking too long to and finally fails without error.

Comment: Backup Restore is no option. This is simple not allowed/supported thats way it is "so hard".